# How to use micro-services into core application/framework?

Tags: rest, microservices

For example I have two micro-services, how can I use those services in my core application?

I know the communication will be through REST API.

My question is, should I create those services as sub-modules?

If my question seems not clear to you then assume I am not clear about micro-services. Thus better explanation will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking, whether services should be in same (maven, gradle) project?

Comment: If you're asking how to use the microservices you are planning on building and what should go into them, then you probably shouldn't use microservices.

Comment: microservices should be a independent applications with own IP and/or Port. So each microservice should be an extra project.

Comment: @bartac Yes. I want to implement micro-service architecture in one of my project which is initially small project but it will grow on time.

I am confused in one matter. For example I have core application written in server side language. Now I have developed a micro service and that is also using server side language. Then calling a REST api from core application to service will not take long time?

Comment: @Muhammed Imran Hussain it will take longer than inprocess call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microservices shouldn't be *sub-modules* of some *core* module.

Imagine microservices as quite independent entities.
They might be written *eventually* in the same programming language as the core module but it's not necessary. They are communicating through REST API after all. You can process REST API with nearly all programming languages.

The least is the compile or runtime dependency between such kind of services it's the better. The best if services can be implemented by different group of developers, probably from different companies or cultures. Also, it's good if (micro)services can ride out temporary outages of other (micro)services in production.

A [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033158.do) to read.